# Let $G$ be a group, $H\le G$, $N\unlhd G$ with $\gcd(|N|, |G:N|)=1$. Show that $H\le N$ iff $|H|$ divides $|N|$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

> Let $G$ be a group, $H\le G$, $N\unlhd G$ with $\gcd(|N|, |G:N|)=1$. Show that $H\le N$ iff $|H|$ divides $|N|$.

So, obviously we can see that if $H\le N$ we have that $|H|$ divides $|N|$. Proving the other way, that $|H|$ divides $|N|$ implies $H\le N$, seems tricker.

I see that I've got that $|G:N|$ is coprime to $|N|,$ so if $|H|$ divides $|N|,$ it can't be in my quotient group of $G/N$ ... but I don't see why I even care about that. There is most likely some connection between $H$ not being contained in the quotient $G/N$ and therefore needing to be contained within $N$ that I can't find (although thats a longshot guess).

Thanks.

Comment: Does look like a job for Lagrange...

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Consider the image of $H$ in $G/N$

Comment: If |H| divides |N|, then |H| is coprime to [G:N] as well, no? So can I even make a clean function from H $\to$ G/N?

Comment: Hint: Because $N$ is normal, we know that $HN$ is a subgroup of $G$ and furthermore the isomorphism laws give $HN/N\cong H/(N\cap H)$. What can you say about the order of $HN/N$ in light of that?

Comment: But I have this nagging feeling that this very question has already been handled on our site? Did you search before asking?

Comment: Sorry, I think I did a poor job of searching - just looked at related results as I typed the question. However, I think I've made progress but have a problem. We know N is normal in G so we can easily make G/N, and $H\leG$ so we can shove H into whatever function $f:G\toG/N we used to make G/N and blah blah. so hopefully at this point I can use the fact that |N| and [G:N] are coprime to show that f(H) = 1 implying $H\inKer(f)$ implying $H\leN$. But I just made this $f:G\toG/N$ up so I can't really say its homo, but if I could then it would be easy I think? Thanks

Comment: wow, I suck with MathJax, but whatever, I can just define a homomorphism to do what I want it to do. Or so it seems. Thanks for the help

Comment: "iff" is not an initialism; so "i.f.f." is incorrect.